# Division of two counted values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

Hi Guys I'm new to SQL I'm trying to divide the output value as explained with the code below

Tried this but it didn't work

```
SELECT COUNT(DATE_COMPLETE)/COUNT(SUB_SYS) AS FINAL 
FROM VW_TWCOMPLETION
```

I'm using this code where SUB_SYS has value like A,B,C AND DATE_COMPLETE is a Date value like 11/19/2019 ,12/19/2019 , 13/19/2019

```
SELECT  SUB_SYS ,COUNT(SUB_SYS) AS TOTAL , COUNT(DATE_COMPLETE) AS COMPLETE
FROM VW_TWCOMPLETION
GROUP BY SUB_SYS
ORDER BY SUB_SYS
```

I want to Divide the output I get from the count as `COMPLETE/TOTAL`
How can I divide these output values?

```
Table Data

SUB_SYS         

MG1-AS-PWER-05-0

MG1-AS-PWER-06-0

MG1-AS-SPAL-05-0

MG1-AS-SPAL-07-0

TOTAL

6

11

4

17

12

COMPLETE

0

6

0

2

1

0
```

FINAL I AM GETTING WITH BELOW CODE IS

0

0

0

0

0

Comment: "Tried this but it didn't work". What does that mean? Did you get an error message? Did you get the wrong result?

Comment: I got "0" instead of Multiple outputs.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like below

```
   with cte as
  (
   SELECT  SUB_SYS ,COUNT(SUB_SYS) AS TOTAL , COUNT(DATE_COMPLETE) AS COMPLETE
   FROM VW_TWCOMPLETION
   GROUP BY SUB_SYS

  ) select SUB_SYS, (COMPLETE*1.0) /NULLIF(TOTAL,0) as final from cte ORDER BY SUB_SYS
```

Comment: Zaynul  i am getting this error "Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: @Mani check the updated answer or use order by in outer query not inside cte

Comment: the code is working but i am not getting any output its all 0.
btw i change it to COMPLETE/TOTAL

Comment: share your table's data in the question otherwise, no one can say you why you are not getting your expected output

Comment: hope this helps.